# Horror/Creepy TV series, cartoon, decades odd ago (likely cable/teletoon)

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror, cartoon

TV series, cartoon, sort of twilight zone for kids. I remember the intro scene had one of the main characters at one point say "now things get creepy" or words to that effect. The intro scene had a ghostly carriage (drawn by skeletal horses, driven by the reaper) and a beating heart in it. I remember one episode was about a boy who never took care of his pets, a shop keeper that turned out to be a toad he had has a pet that came back for vengeance turned him into a small rodent like creature. I remember at one point his mother is burying a goldfish her neglected and he says he'd like something cool like a dolphin.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:American_children%27s_animated_horror_television_series

Comment: What channel (in which country) did you see it? What year was it?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I'm in Canada, I Can't remember for certain the channel but I think it was teletoon. In terms of year...not certain, early 2000s I think.

Comment: @Valorum, looked through the list, not mentioned there I'm afraid but thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it was [Moville Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moville_Mysteries), specifically '*Pet Shop Of No Return*'

> Emil, a boy who never takes care of his pets, is given exclusive pets from a mysterious man who will only sell to Emil.

[image]

Comment: Even for a self-answer, you need to specify why it matches.

Comment: And don't forget to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark in about 45 hours.